# jQuery / JavaScript find and replace with RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a number of pages that contain phone number in this format xxx-xxx-xxxx.
These phone numbers are not links, what I need to do it write some script that first finds these phone numbers. This is what I have got for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var content = $(".main").text();
var phoneNumber = content.match(/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/)

alert(phoneNumber);
});
```

This works in so much that is captures the number, what I need to do now is replace that phone number on the page with

```
'<a href=" onclick=" ... "' + 'tel:' + phoneNumber + '">' + 'originalPhoneNumber' + '</a>'
```

However I am totally lost at this point. Can I use `.replaceWith()` in jQuery?

**EDIT**:

Okay I tried to modify the code to include the second attribute i wanted:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $(".main").html();
    content = content.replace(/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g, function(v){
        return $('<a>').attr({
            href: "tel:"+v,
            onclick: "ga('send', 'event', 'lead', 'phone call', 'call');"
        }).html(v)[0].outerHTML;
    });

    $('.main').html(content);
});
```

It is still adding the href but it is ignoring the onclick.

Comment: *"Can I use `.replaceWith()` in jQuery?"* `.replaceWith()` works with DOM elements, not with strings.

Comment: @FelixKling The OP wanted to use replace method of regex...

Comment: You should do this job on server side once and for all and then you save the page with the changes, otherwise the replacements would be performed each time you load the page.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte absolutely I agree but at the moment that's not an option. :/

Comment: `outereHTML` is both not backward compatible and not jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace all matching strings in an element with a tel: link

```
<div class = "main">333-333-3333 444-444-4444</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var content = $(".main").text();

    content = content.replace(/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g, function(v){
        return $('<a>').attr('class', set.classname).attr('href', 'tel:'+v).html(v).wrap('<a>').parent().html();
    });

    $('.main').html(content);

</script>
```

Or more neatly implemented as :

```
    $.fn.extend({
        tel : function(def) {

            var set = {
                regex : /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g,
                classname : ""
            }

            $.extend(true, set, def);

            var c = $(this).html();

            c = c.replace(set.regex, function(v){
                return $('<a>').attr('class', set.classname).attr('href', 'tel:'+v).html(v).wrap('<a>').parent().html();
            });

            $(this).html(c);
            return this;
        }
    });

    // default regex: 000-000-0000
    $('.main').tel();       

    // default regex: 000-000-0000 <a> class of tel-link applied
    $('.main').tel({ classname : "tel-link" });             

    // override regex: 0000-0000-000    
    $('.main').tel({ regex: /\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{3}/g });
```

Comment: Thank you this does indeed work, I have updated my original question about the second attribute also.

Comment: return $('<a>').attr('class', set.classname).attr('href', 'tel:'+v).attr('onclick', 'alert("hello")').html(v).wrap('<a>').parent().html();